# Nginx limit number of ip's connected to server

Tags: nginx

Can I limit number of ip's connected to server using nginx?
I want to limit number of clients that can access example.com/download at the same time

I don't want to limit connections per ip, each ip can have multiple connections to server

I searched everywhere but I couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can limit specific url in nginx.

For that you need to use `limit_conn_zone` and `limit_conn`

```
http {
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=download:10m;
    server {
        location /download {
            limit_conn download 10; #here you can set limit like 10,20,30 etc..
        }
    }
}
```